# Unable to send a message with AMQP.Lite and IBMMQ 8.0

Tags: c#, azure, ibm-mq, amqp

I'm developing a new service based on our infrastructure that uses IBMMQ 8.0 (I've to admit that I'm not a guru of IBMMQ and I've used it as a simple integration without diving in it's implementation).

I'm trying right now to use It with [amqpnetlite](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) (in order to use it with .NET Core).

Till now here's my snippet

```
 Address address = new Address("amqp://10.112.62.102:1414");
        Connection connection = new Connection(address);
        Session session = new Session(connection);

        Message message = new Message("Hello AMQP!");
         var sender = new SenderLink(session, "AONMQCOL1", "MQ_TEST");
        sender.Send(message);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent Hello AMQP!");
```

I got an exception AmqpException: The transport 'TcpTransport' is closed. when performing the Send. On the connection object I've got IsClosed = false so I think the connection is open.

Just as confirmation, what should I put as "address" and "name" on the SenderLink's constructor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact version of MQ Server you are running?  i.e. issue the ***dspmqver*** command.

You need to be at Command Level 801 which was added in Fixack 2 of IBM MQ v8.  i.e. IBM MQ v8.0.0.2.  See ***[here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.amqp.doc/tamqp_creating.htm)*** for more details.

Did you start the AMQP service and then start the channel?

i.e. runmqsc commands:

```
START SERVICE(SYSTEM.AMQP.SERVICE)

START CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.AMQP)
```

Finally, are you connecting to the correct port #?  The default port # is 5672.